# Working as contractor in USA as foreign citizen (EU)

Tags: usa, freelance, working-visas

I'm an EU-Citizen and I'd like to consider opportunity of working in USA as IT-specialist (developer).

If I find an opportunity to work there as contractor (freelancer), can I simply register my company there? Or there are special requirements to be met? How do I apply for VISA in that case?

As far as I know, USA grants VISA to computer specialists without any problem, because they are needed there, if they want to be employed there. Do the same applies to contractors?

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Being a contractor is not the same as being a business owner. In most EU countries a freelancer is explicitly NOT a business owner, because there is no legal entity that would constitute a business. Instead, the freelancer is the legal entity who signs contracts.

Comment: @nikola it's already narrowed to contracting. Most EU-countries require registering company for freelancing as contractor, even if it's not a company under trade law.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having a company registered in the US doesn't allow you to be present in the US to do work.

The most common visa that computer specialists get is [H1B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) but with that you can't really be a freelancer.  You will need to be employed by a company in the US which means also that your employer have to sponsor an H1 for you.  And if I remember correctly self-sponsoring won't work in this case.

There are other visas available also but have more restrictions and requirements then the H1, such as [L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-1_visa), O, P, and also [E visas](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/permanent-workers) but it also won't work without a full employment at the US company.

There is also an [investment visa available](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-fifth-preference-eb-5/eb-5-immigrant-investor) but you will need to invest about $1M to qualify.

So getting to working in the US legally isn't that simple from immigration point of view.

Comment: OP could presumably run his business from his home in Europe, and travel as needed on a B1 visa.  He would have to avoid doing too much work while in the US on that visa, but attending meetings would, for example, be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

There is [E-2 Treaty Investors](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/e-2-treaty-investors) visa. Requirements are:

> - Be a national of a country with which the United States maintains a treaty of commerce and navigation
> - Have invested, or be actively in the process of investing, a substantial amount of capital in a bona fide enterprise in the United
>     States
> - Be seeking to enter the United States solely to develop and direct the investment enterprise.  This is established by showing at least
>     50% ownership of the enterprise or possession of operational control
>     through a managerial position or other corporate device.

It's vague on how much investment is required. There have been people who have been given that visa with investments as little as $25,000, but also people rejected with investment in excess of $100,000.

Of course it's not gonna be "freelance", you'd have to establish actual enterprise.

Comment: And you'll have to demonstrate growth of your business (hire people!) if you want to apply for permanent residency later on. Although E-2 is semi-dual-intent, if your end goal is permanent residency, it's a very risky visa because your business is re-evaluated every 2 years and if it is considered to be "marginal" with no growth perspective, your visa will probably not be extended.